# Linting with splint: Preprocessor behaves different from compiler

Tags: c, static-analysis, splint

I'm trying to lint C code with splint. However, I'm including the standard `lua.h` header file, which does some preprocessing to set internal types. GCC and splint take different paths. I've narrowed this down to the following code:

```
#include <limits.h>     
#if defined(LLONG_MAX)     
    // GCC path (we're good)     
#else                                                                                                                                       
    // splint path     
    #error "Compiler does not support 'long long'. Use option '-DLUA_32BITS' or '-DLUA_C89_NUMBERS' (see file 'luaconf.h' for details)"    
#endif
```

In gcc, `LLONG_MAX` is defined, which then compiles correctly. In splint, the `#else` path is taken, since `LLONG_MAX` is not defined. I don't set any additional flags for gcc, just plain `gcc -c test.c`. I can define `LLONG_MAX` for splint which then in turn processes files seemingly correct, but I would like to know that it does looks at the same code as gcc (there is of course more preprocessing, so it might see different code). How do I get process the code like gcc?

Comment: Which version of C is `splint` working with?  If it's C90, LLONG_MAX wouldn't be defined.

Comment: Maybe add required preprocessor symbol definitions to the command line?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm using splint `3.1.2a`, the manpage states the default standard library (which of course does not really says something about the language version) is ISO C99. I'm not sure how else to answer this question.

Comment: @Bodo, well as I mentioned I can define `LLONG_MAX`, but I find it difficult to find out which flags I'd need to set. In the real code, the preprocessing section of relevant files is hundreds of lines.

Comment: Nor me — I don't use `splint`.  I'd probably look for `__STDC_VERSION__` and test that.  I'd look for other C99 additions to `<limits.h>` (`ULONG_MAX`, …) to see whether it's an oversight in `splint`.

Comment: LLONG_MAX has been mandatory standard C and part of limits.h for 24 years by now. Any tool failing to find it belongs on a museum, not on a development department...

Comment: @pschulz You could check under which conditions `limits.h` defines `LLONG_MAX` and try to define/undefine symbols as necessary to get `LLONG_MAX`.

Comment: @Lundin You might be right. I'm just getting started with linting, but perhaps I have to find a different tool...

Comment: Generally the professional tools are of poor quality and the open source ones are even worse. This isn't really a mature branch of the software industry yet.

Comment: Ok, well, that's good to know. I've been working with `gcc -fanalyzer` as well as clang static analyzer, but I wanted to try some other options, maximizing found errors. The code flagged by splint after some tweaking some preprocesser defines looked reasonable, so if I end up with a sensible solution I'll post it as an answer.